# Java standard out produces no output

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble.  This code doesn't raise any compile-time errors,  however `System.out.println` is not displaying.  It should display how that you should color all four sides.  Am I making a mistake in the for loop or is it with the structure?

See code below:

```
public interface Colorable {
    // Abstract to be called later
    public abstract String howToColor();

}

public class HowToColour {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}

public class TestColorable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] obj1 = { 
            new Square(), 
            new Rectangle(), 
            new Rhombus(),
            new Parallelogram(), 
            new Trapezium() 
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++) {
            if (obj1[i] instanceof Colorable) {
                System.out.println(((Colorable) obj1[i]).howToColor());
            } else {
                System.out.println("This shape is not to be colored");

            }
        }
    }
}

class GeometricOgject {

}

// Initial Method to use the interface
class Square extends GeometricOgject implements Colorable {
    @Override
    public String howToColor() {
        return "Square: Color all four sides";
    }
}

// Method to use an interface in an abstract class
abstract class FourSides implements Colorable {

}

class Rectangle extends FourSides {
    @Override
    public String howToColor() {
        return "Rectangle: color all four sides";
    }
}

class Rhombus extends FourSides {
    @Override
    public String howToColor() {
        return "Rhombus: color all four sides";
    }
}

class Parallelogram extends FourSides {
    @Override
    public String howToColor() {
        return "Parallelogram: color all for sides";
    }
}

class Trapezium extends FourSides {
    @Override
    public String howToColor() {
        return "Trapezium: color all four sides";
    }
}
```

Comment: are these all in separate files?  How are you invoking this?

Comment: There are two `main()`s.

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: If you clean this up (remove "public" from Colorable interface, remove stray close-comment before TestColorable) put it all in a file named TestColorable.java and compile it, then "java TestColorable" prints the four "howToColor" messages just fine.

Comment: I have them in three files one of which is testColorable.  I removed the "public" but I am not seeing the stray close-comment.  Can you direct me to it?

Answer (score 3):

If this is all in one file I can see that there is a potential conflict with the declaration of two classes having a main function.  Coincidentally one of your mains is empty and that could be the one being executed.  If these are in different files you should just be able to execute this on the command line:

```
java TestColorable
```

what I presume is happening, is the equivalent of:

```
java HowToColour
```

do the following, each in its **OWN FILE**:

```
public class HowToColour  
{  
    //implementation 
}    

public class TestColorable  
{  
   //implementation
}  

javac TestColorable.java  
javac HowToColour.java  

java TestColorable  
   **output will go here**
java HowToColour  
   **no output here**
```

Comment: Both the classes are *public*. They cannot be in the same file.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal good catch.  However, OP still hasn't been very forthcoming with how the code is being executed.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I did. It said, "If this is all in one file.." though OP mentioned "The code has no errors and compiles fine."

Comment: They are in 3 separate files:  HowToColor, Colorable, testColorable